# Как сделать WebView с зумом в Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, мобильная-разработка, xamarin.forms

Все туториалы о том как сделать это, которые я находил слишком сложны, возможно есть способ легче?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне пока не приходилось проверять подобное на iOS в Xamarin.Forms, но на Android данный способ работать точно будет.

Добавьте к коду своего WebView две библиотеки:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
```

Теперь вы можете включить зум в WebView всего в две строчки кода:

```
MyWebView.On<Android>().EnableZoomControls(true); //Зум жестами
MyWebView.On<Android>().DisplayZoomControls(false); //Зум кнопками + - на экране
```

Возможно вы увидите вот такую ошибку:

```
"WebView" является неоднозначной ссылкой между
"Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.WebView" и
"Xamarin.Forms.WebView".
```

Она исправляется добавлением

```
using WebView = Xamarin.Forms.WebView;
```

к вашим библиотекам.

Вот полный код моего шаблона для WebView с зумом на C#

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using WebView = Xamarin.Forms.WebView;

namespace WebViewPattern
{
    public class customWebView : ContentPage
    {
        WebView MyWebView;

        public customWebView()
        {
            //Убирает верхний тулбар
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            MyWebView = new WebView
            {
                Source = "google.com",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            MyWebView.On<Android>().EnableZoomControls(true);
            MyWebView.On<Android>().DisplayZoomControls(false);
            this.Content = new StackLayout { Children = { MyWebView } };
        }
    }
}
```